# Can I add an animation to a React Native navigation button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a button in react native, that I am using to navigate to another screen in my Drawer navigator (in addition to using the drawer screen itself). However, the transition is very abrupt. It it possible to have some kind of animation to make it smoother?

I have seen the docs for the transitioner, but these do not appear to be for a functional component like the screen the button is on. Is there any help?

Here is my button:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.buttonContainer}
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("SocialScreen")}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Socials</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you please tell more about animation like which type of animation, and what is is mean by abrupt transition?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add animation there.

I am attaching link of library with detail explanation [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/next/docs/style-animations/)

Kindly comment if you face any error.